# When I'm trying to access the objects from props in React not able to access it using map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the error I'm getting

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmBQB.png

This is the Myprops.js file

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHrBb.png

This is my index.js file

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kOsV.png

Comment: It's an object not an array so obviously it does not have property map, just skip the map function altogether and insert the callback directly into the code, just replace the "user" with "carinfo"

Comment: Please, copy your code instead attaching images.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of links to images... images aren't searchable and are more difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `carinfo` is not an array but an object. That's the reason you cannot call `map` function. It should be:

```
const carinfo = [{ name: "Ford", model: "Mustang" }];
```

Also, your `Myprops` component should be:

```
  const Myprops = (props) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {props.carinfo.map(c => <h1>{c.name}</h1>)}
      ...
  }
```

Comment: Okay I will try with it

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to loop over an object.

If you plan on having multiple carinfo objects in the future use an array instead.

index.js

```
const carinfos = [
  { name: "Ford", model: "mustang"},
  // more carinfo objects ...
]
// render you component
```

MyProps.js

```
const MyProps = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.carinfos.map(info => <h1>{info.name}</h1>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you only have one object, you do not need the array nor the map function.

```
const MyProps = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.carinfo.name}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Array.map()* is for **Array**, your props is an Object.
You have to use *for as* or *for in.*
Or you can do a map using

```
Object.keys(myObject).map(var => {
    // Things
})
```